# Data catalog tools supporting multi tenancy and data isolation

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, data-dictionary, azure-data-catalog

I am looking for a Data Catalog tool like Azure Data Catalog which will support multitenancy in Azure Data Lake Gen2 environment as a data source. With this functionality, multiple users (different tenants) should be able to search their specific data (data lake folder) using any metadata tool. Does Azure Data Catalog support this multitenancy, data isolation? Can you please suggest few other tools which will handle such type of multitenancy and data isolation efficiently?

Answer (score 0):

Azure Data Catalog is designed to support a single tenant at a time.